# Is there any way to store one week back data(like walking steps in CMStepCounter(7 days data)) in CoreData in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an requirement like, i need to store one week back data (NSDictionary/NSMUtableArray) in Core data

For Example: Today's date : `15th_January_2016`

I need to store data from (`14th_January_2016 to 8th_January_2016`) . There is no need to store Today's data in Core Data

another example 
like : If `16th_01_2016` ===> means i need to store data from `15th_01_2016 to 9th_01_2016`

If any one knows the solution/sample code.

Comment: What have you tried?  What entities do you have?  You can store whatever date you want in core data.  Why do you think it would matter at all?

Comment: I have around 15 NSString's values are there. I want to store those in core data

Comment: Core Data is an object persistence framework.  Are these strings part of an object, or are they a random collection?  Why do you want them in core data?

Comment: Ok @Avi, I am little bit confused in this, Can you just suggested me the best approach how to do this by comparing day wise(7 day's back data)

Comment: I have no clue what your data looks like.  Look at the documentation for `NSCalendar`, `NSDate` and `NSDateComponents`.  Between those 3, you'll find what you need to compare dates and figure out which data you want to save.

Comment: ThanQ for you're suggestion @Avi, I will try to do this ====> One more thing my data looks like normal string/double values only===> 55, 66, 47, 56, 89, @"Hello Stack" and etc..

Comment: I don't get it. How can you store yesterdays data today when the user powers off the device? Don't save today -> there will be no data to save tomorrow... What's the point here? I could imagine that the requirement is to keep data for one week.

Comment: Yes, @ lupz , you're right.currently, i am developing an app like it's a  Daily bases app user should enter some data in UITextfields, I need to store those data in daily bases like upto 1 week only

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you add a `creationDate` attribute to your data entries.
When the user produces data you can save the current date along with the user data.
Every now and then (e.g. on app startup, only once every day) you can check for entries that are older than a week and delete them.

First of all you need a reference date that is one week ago. You should be able to get it like this:

```
NSCalendar       *calendar;
NSDateComponents *comps;
NSDate           *oneWeekAgo;

calendar   = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
comps      = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setDay:-8];

oneWeekAgo = [calendar
              dateByAddingComponents:comps
                              toDate:[NSDate date]
                             options:0];
[comps release];
```

Then you need to fetch all the entries that have a smaller `creationDate` (are older) than the reference:

```
NSArray        *oldEntries;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest;
NSPredicate    *predicate;

fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]
                initWithEntityName:@"<your entry name>"];
predicate    = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                @"creationDate < %@", oneWeekAgo];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
oldEntries   = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
[fetchRequest release];
```

You can then delete each of the old entries using
`[NSManagedObjectContext deleteObject:<the entry>]`.

Comment: ThanQ. I tried this way only by using Core data but i am unable to delete older than a week  .. If you don't mine. Can you please provide me some sample code regarding this iisue

Answer (score 1):

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *versionTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *companyTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *dateStringRef;
@property (strong) NSManagedObject *device;
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender;
```

in .m class

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
    context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
}
return context;
}

 - (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSDate *sevenDaysBeforeDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: -  (60.0f*60.0f*24.0f*7)];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@) AND (date <= %@)", sevenDaysBeforeDate, [NSDate date]];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor   sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] ;
request.sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Device" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]]];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
Device *newDevice =[results objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *nameStr = newDevice.name;
NSLog(@"%@",nameStr);
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
if (self.device) {
    [self.nameTextField setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"name"]];
    [self.versionTextField setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"version"]];
    [self.companyTextField setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"company"]];
}
 }
 - (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
df.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy";
  self.dateStringRef = [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];  // Don't use     leading caps on variables
//NSLog(@"%@", self.dateStringRef);
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    // Create a new device
NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription    insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Device" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newDevice setValue:self.nameTextField.text forKey:@"name"];
    [newDevice setValue:self.versionTextField.text forKey:@"version"];
    [newDevice setValue:self.companyTextField.text forKey:@"company"];
    [newDevice setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"date"];

NSError *error = nil;
// Save the object to persistent store
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```